# StructuredStreaming error - pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: batch 44 doesn't exist

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm running a StructuredStreaming program on GCP Dataproc, which reads data from Kafka, does some processing and puts processed data back into Kafka.
The programs was running fine, when i killed it (to make minor change),
and then re-started it.

It is giving me the error - pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: batch 44 doesn't exist

```
22/02/25 22:14:08 ERROR org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 0b73937f-1140-40fe-b201-cf4b7443b599, runId = 43c9242d-993a-4b9a-be2b-04d8c9e05b06] terminated with error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: batch 44 doesn't exist
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$populateStartOffsets$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:286)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.populateStartOffsets(MicroBatchExecution.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:197)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:334)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:244)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/0149aedd804c42f288718e013fb16f9c/StructuredStreaming_GCP_Versa_Sase_gcloud.py", line 609, in <module>
    query.awaitTermination()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 101, in awaitTermination
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: batch 44 doesn't exist
```

Question - what is the cause of this error and how to debug/fix ?
Also, i notice that the checkpoint location gets corrupted occassionaly, when i do multiple restarts. After checkpoint corruption, it does not return any records

For the above issue(as well as when the checkpoint was corrupted), when i cleared the checkpoint location and re-started the program, it went though fine.

Pls note:
while doing readStream, i've enabled failOnDataLoss=false

here is the readStream command, with the failOnDataLoss=false:

```
df_stream = spark.readStream.format('kafka') \
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL") \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", ssl_truststore_location) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", ssl_truststore_password) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", ssl_keystore_location) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", ssl_keystore_password) \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",kafkaBrokers)\
    .option("subscribe", topic) \
    .option("kafka.group.id", consumerGroupId)\
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
    .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 5000) \
    .load()
```

any input on this ?
tia!

Comment: I've 2 guesses: either the Kafka topic is compacted (which may do gaps in the IDs) or the log retention removed the data from the topic.

Comment: @GaborSomogyi - as i mentioned in the description, while doing readStream, i've enabled failOnDataLoss=false .. so, per my understanding - this should not fail even if the batch is removed due to log retention .. is that not correct ? Pls note. i've updated the description with the readStream command as well